# What is the most basic way for Node.js to send/return plain-text data to/from MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

*With the following Node.js architecture: index.js + server.js + router.js + requestHandlers.js*

Am new to javascript application programming.. How does Node.js talk to MongoDB in the most basic way?

*Is mongoose necessary? If so, what is a basic implementation?*

requestHandlers.js:

```
    var querystring = require("querystring"),
    fs = require("fs");

function start(response, postData) {
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

    var body = '<html>'+
        '<head>'+
        '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" '+
        'content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'+
        '</head>'+
        '<body>'+
        '<form action="/upload" method="post">'+
        '<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>'+
        '<input type="submit" value="Submit text" />'+
        '</form>'+
        '</body>'+
        '</html>';

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write(body);
        response.end();
}

function upload(response, postData) {
    console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("You've sent the text: "+
    querystring.parse(postData).text);
    response.end();
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
exports.show = show;
```

Answer (score 0):

Im very new to nodejs myself so my answers may not be the most adequate but i think sending data to node would be done the same way its done in PHP, mostly ajax calls.

and to parse the submitted data, you can use (in node express), or using querystring as youve done.

```
  app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: __dirname + '/tmp', }));
```

and then access the submitted variables using request.body.yourvariable
and request.files for uploaded files.

and mongoose is not necessary, but its recommended. 
It provides additional functionality to mongo.

Comment: really appreciate the answer.. is node express an aspect of node, or part of the express.js framework?

Comment: express is a framework built using node so express can do everything node can, pluss some more. 
It has routing, views, url parser etc etc.

and mongoose is built based on mongo, so it takes what mongo has, and adds some more functionality to it

Comment: I would recommend the express home page guide for installing express
http://expressjs.com/guide.html
and its API and sample app for setting your site up.

for mongo 
http://theholmesoffice.com/node-js-express-and-mongoose/

You could also google and find a sample app , and learn from their code.